# Facebook Connect Android -- using stream.publish @ http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am getting the following error:

```xml
<error_code>104</error_code>
<error_msg>Incorrect signature</error_msg>
```

What should I be setting contentType type as? Should I set as:

```
String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

or

```
String contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + kStringBoundary;
```

This is how I am writing the stream:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
OutputStream out = null;
InputStream in = null;
try {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) _loadingURL.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    if (method != null) {
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        if ("POST".equals(method)) {
            //"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            String contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + kStringBoundary;
            //String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
        }

        // Cookies are used in FBPermissionDialog and FBFeedDialog to
        // retrieve logged user
       conn.connect();
       out = conn.getOutputStream();
       if ("POST".equals(method)) {
            String body = generatePostBody(postParams);
            if (body != null) {
                out.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }
        }
        in = conn.getInputStream();
```

Here's the method I am using to publish the stream:

```
private void publishFeed(String themessage) {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, FBFeedActivity.class);
   // intent.putExtra("userMessagePrompt", themessage);
  //  intent.putExtra("attachment", 
    Map<String, String> getParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // getParams.put("display", "touch");
    // getParams.put("callback", "fbconnect://success");
    // getParams.put("cancel", "fbconnect://cancel");

     Map<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

     postParams.put("api_key", _session.getApiKey());
     postParams.put("method", "stream.publish");
     postParams.put("session_key", _session.getSessionKey());
     postParams.put("user_message", "TESTING 123");
    // postParams.put("preview", "1");
     postParams.put("attachment", "{\"name\":\"Facebook Connect for Android\",\"href\":\"http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/\",\"caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}");
    // postParams.put("user_message_prompt", "22222");


     try {
         loadURL("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php", "POST", getParams, postParams);
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Here is generatePostBody() :

```
private String generatePostBody(Map<String, String> params) {
    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder endLine = new StringBuilder("\r\n--").append(kStringBoundary).append("\r\n");

    body.append("--").append(kStringBoundary).append("\r\n");

    for (Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(entry.getKey()).append("\"\r\n\r\n");
        String value = entry.getValue();
        if ("user_message_prompt".equals(entry.getKey())) {
            body.append(value);
        }
        else {
            body.append(CcUtil.encode(value));
        }

        body.append(endLine);
    }

    return body.toString();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How is `loadURL()` method implemented? PS. Please re-edit your post, we can't read some code here....

Answer (score 0):

This is from **Facebook** Developers Wiki: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API

> **Note**: If you manually form your HTTP
>   POST requests to Facebook, you must
>   include the request data in the POST
>   body. In addition, you should include
>   a Content-Type: header of
>   *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.

Use **multipart/form-data** when uploading files only (e.g. Photos.upload on Facebook API)

Also, Based on this API reference, http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/How_Facebook_Authenticates_Your_Application, this is what you're doing wrong.

1) Don't use `HashMap` to store Facebook parameters. Parameters must be `sorted` by their key. Rather use `SortedMap` interface and use `TreeMap` to store Facebook parameters.

2) **Always** include the `sig` parameter in the map **before** sending the call to Facebook. You're getting a "104 Incorrect signature" because Facebook doesn't find the `sig` parameter in your request.

The reference (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/How_Facebook_Authenticates_Your_Application) shows exactly how to create a MD5 signature which facebook uses.

Here's how to quickly create a `sig` value for Facebook.

```
String hashString = "";
        Map<String, String> sortedMap = null;
        if (parameters instanceof TreeMap) {
            sortedMap = (TreeMap<String, String>) parameters; 
        } else {
            sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(parameters);
        }

        try {
            Iterator<String> iter = sortedMap.keySet().iterator();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            synchronized (iter) {
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iter.next();
                    sb.append(key);
                    sb.append("=");
                    String value = sortedMap.get(key);
                    sb.append(value == null ? "" : value);
                }
            }
            sb.append(secret);

            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] digested = digest.digest(sb.toString().getBytes());

            BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digested);
            hashString = bigInt.toString(16);
            while (hashString.length() < 32) {
                hashString = "0" + hashString;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }

        return hashString;
```