# How to post a Msg on Facebook using graph in android without web-view?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

After implementation of twitter in my app Now i try to implement Facebook for my app, and I found   [Facebook SDK for android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)
I use that code for login, but problem is that I want to publish a msg on a buttons click without opening web-view. I found few links on this but no one works for me.
I exactly want that same thing 
[How to post on facebook wall using Facebook android SDK, without opening dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213767/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-using-facebook-android-sdk-without-opening-dialog-b)
I use the answer for but it five following error...Even I have allow application to use my information.

> Key description expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value  was returned.
>
> 01-24 10:37:33.567: DEBUG/Tests(479): got response: {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"}}

Answer (score 1):

Use the Android SDK and make sure to request the `publish_stream` permission.

Comment: probably you are forgetting to request "publish_stream" permission

Answer (score 0):

use this SDK defenately heplful to u

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: I am already using this but...It show dialogbox to post a feed.

Answer (score 0):

You need an auth token and use it with Graph API.
You can get the token via `mFacebook.getAccessToken()` method.
Assuming *mFacebook* is an authenticated Facebook instance (via `authorize` method)

Answer (score 0):

You should have requested permission"message" when you called authorize on the Facebook object.

Regards stéphane