# Error OAuthException 2500 while posting with facebook graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writting app integrated with facebook. I want to post to wall without post dialog. I try to use [code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4376415/987632), but I got an error

```
{"error":
    {"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
     "type":"OAuthException",
     "code":2500
    }
}
```

I login user with this code

```
    public void authorize() {
    mFacebook.authorize(mActivity, new String[] { "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString("access_token", mFacebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong("access_expires", mFacebook.getAccessExpires());
            editor.commit();

            mLoginStateView.setImageResource(mAuthorizedDrawableRes);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}
```

Please, explain me what am I doing wrong?

[ADDED]

If I try to post with `mFacebook.dialog(currentActivity, "stream.publish", params, new UpdateStatusListener());` it works. Please, help me!

Comment: Maybe I need any other permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I've done it. But it looks like a bug or magic...
LogCat after authorize method (Facebook's log is enabled)

```
Facebook-authorize: Login Success! access_token=AAAHL4f6XMS0BAHNJKpoGAUAeGDlynRt1s5XPdBPRWGfILGOTZB4OSEGi4HBPLZBXDWqK2RIO8disDtzxHBYSvL3bZAnHkU5hAVK9oqWhAZDZD expires=1356040438476
```

But then I try post with

```
String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

Function request from Facebook.java :

```
public String request(String graphPath, Bundle params, String httpMethod)
        throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
params.putString("format", "json");
if (isSessionValid()) {
    params.putString(TOKEN, getAccessToken());
}
String url = (graphPath != null) ? GRAPH_BASE_URL + graphPath : RESTSERVER_URL;
return Util.openUrl(url, httpMethod, params);
}
```

I see in debugger, that Facebook's function `isSessionValid()` returns `false` and `mAccessToken = null`. I don't know why it is so, and why it returns `true` sometimes afterwards (yes, I understand that it is impossible). Explaine me, please, if you know.

This code solved my problem (it just re-sets access token)

```
if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()){
    String token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    mFacebook.setAccessToken(token);
    mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
}
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", msg);
parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
    Log.e(Const.LOG_TAG, "Blank response");
} else {
    Log.d(Const.LOG_TAG, response);
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote inside the `if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid())` should have be done in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Oh, you right again =) and I understood why `mAccessToken` is not `null` afterwards: I set it in some other my function... I masked my bug very well! =)

Answer (score 1):

A successful authorization would return an access token to your app, which you can then use to perform actions to the Facebook API.  The error message displayed means you do not have a valid access token which means you probably did not authenticate the app correctly.  I would put some logging on the `onFacebookError` and `onError` methods to see what the problem is.

Comment: Thank for your advice, I'll try to log. But if I did not authenticate the app correctly why I can post to wall using "standard" facebook dialog?

Comment: You were right. But I don't understand: I receive a correct access token, why it is null then I try to post...

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem while retrieving albums from facebook. I tested my access_token via [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it was valid. Then I found the error, the final url in `com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(...)` was:
**Invalid-URL1:** 
https:// graph.facebook.com//me/albums?fields=id,name,cover_photo,type,count?access_token={...token..}&format=json&metadata=1
Where it should be:
**Valid - URL2:** 
 https:// graph.facebook.com//me/albums?fields=id,name,cover_photo,type,count&access_token={...token..}&format=json&metadata=1

Note that in URL1 ? is added two times which is not valid so I changed the code as follows
 
Code Changes:
**Previous**

```
com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(...)

    if (method.equals("GET")) {
        url = url + "?" + encodeUrl(params);
    }
```

**Now**

```
com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(...)

    if (method.equals("GET")) {
        if(url.contains ( "?" )==false)
        {
            url = url + "?" + encodeUrl(params);
        }
        else
        {
            url = url + "&" + encodeUrl(params);
        }
    }
```