# Post message to someone else's wall (friend's wall) via Facebook API?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does Facebook allow that **user A** using mobile app posts something (text, image or URL) on **user B's** wall?

I have been searching for this for a couple of days, but I cannot find anything about it in Facebook API docs.

To make it clear, I do not need to post something on my own wall, but on my friend's wall using Facebook API.

Am I right saying that this is not possible/allowed at this moment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213767/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-using-facebook-android-sdk-without-opening-dialog

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov Hm, this seems like link to posting things on YOUR OWN wall. I need to post something on my friends wall directly from a mobile app. Is this more clear now? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896863/post-on-users-friends-facebook-wall-through-android-application?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code to post on another user's wall.

```
Bundle postStatusMessage = new Bundle();

// ADD THE STATUS MESSAGE TO THE BUNDLE
postStatusMessage.putString("message", finalStatusMessage);

Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(userID + "/feed", postStatusMessage, "POST", new StatusUpdateListener(), null);
```

You can also upload a *photo* with the above code, like this:

```
byte[] data = null;

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bmpImageCamera.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle postImgGallery = new Bundle();

// ADD THE PHOTO DATA TO THE BUNDLE
postImgGallery.putByteArray("photo", data);
```

And then use this to check the result.

```
private class StatusUpdateListener extends BaseRequestListener  {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {

    }

}
```

If successfully posted, `String response` in the onComplete() will give you an ID for the post.

**NOTE 1:** The above code uses the older Facebook SDK (Pre v 3.x) so you will have to adapt the code to work with the new SDK if you are using it. It will need a few minor changes.

**NOTE 2:** Facebook has planned to stop the ability to let applications post to other users walls. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/. Going forward, you will need to use the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) option.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is smart not to implement this feature.

Comment: Additionally to NOTE 2: You can use [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/) now, instead of feed dialog, as it is capable of posting Open Graph actions as well.