# How to post on facebook from my android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an android app that saves quotes in a database. I want to add an option Post, to give the user the opportunity to post the quote in his wall in facebook. But I have no idea how to start with it! Can anyone help me and give me some directions of what should I do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: there are tutorials enough on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can look:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984478/3821823

or

Also you look:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Facebook SDK download. Then create your facebook application, enter the key.